# Replacing parsename with some string splitter on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I currently have this query in a stored procedure where I am joining on fields in a table that match parts of a string field in the select table:

```
SELECT EmployeeNum,
       ProjectID,
       LaborHedSeq,
       LaborDtlSeq,
       LaborHrs,
       LaborRate,
       BurdenHrs,
       BurdenRate,
       PayrollDate,
       PhaseID,
       SUM(ROUND(P.ExtCost, 2)) AS GAAmount
INTO #LaborBurden
FROM [ERP].dbo.PartTran P
    LEFT JOIN [ERP].dbo.LaborDtl L ON L.EmployeeNum = PARSENAME(REPLACE(P.TranReference, '|', '.'), 3)
                                  AND L.LaborHedSeq = PARSENAME(REPLACE(P.TranReference, '|', '.'), 2)
                                  AND L.LaborDtlSeq = PARSENAME(REPLACE(P.TranReference, '|', '.'), 1)
WHERE P.TranType = 'ADJ-MTL'
  AND P.InvAdjReason = 'GALabor'
  AND LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(6), P.TranReference), 6) = 'Burden'
  AND EmployeeNum IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EmployeeNum,
         ProjectID,
         LaborHedSeq,
         LaborDtlSeq,
         LaborHrs,
         LaborRate,
         BurdenHrs,
         BurdenRate,
         PayrollDate,
         PhaseID;
```

This had been working fine since there were only 4 sections in the string we were working with. They have now added another section separated by the pipe, so the parsename no longer works. I have been trying to use the String_Split command but this gives me errors when trying to compare the value to the 'Burden' string:

```
SELECT EmployeeNum,
       ProjectID,
       LaborHedSeq,
       LaborDtlSeq,
       LaborHrs,
       LaborRate,
       BurdenHrs,
       BurdenRate,
       PayrollDate,
       PhaseID,
       SUM(ROUND(P.ExtCost, 2)) AS GAAmount
INTO #LaborBurden
FROM [ERP].dbo.PartTran P
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(P.TranReference, '|') s
    LEFT JOIN [ERP].dbo.LaborDtl L ON L.EmployeeNum = s.value
                                  AND L.LaborHedSeq = s.value
                                  AND L.LaborDtlSeq = s.value
WHERE P.TranType = 'ADJ-MTL'
  AND P.InvAdjReason = 'GALabor'
  AND s.value = 'Burden'
  AND EmployeeNum IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EmployeeNum,
         ProjectID,
         LaborHedSeq,
         LaborDtlSeq,
         LaborHrs,
         LaborRate,
         BurdenHrs,
         BurdenRate,
         PayrollDate,
         PhaseID;
```

I don't know what the string split is really retuning so I am probably using it wrong. Does anyone know a way I can have the join statement use just the parts of the string I need as in the first example?

Comment: Seems like you need to fix your design; that is the *real* solution.

Comment: Also, on a seperate note, `LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(6), P.TranReference), 6) = 'Burden'` isn't SARGable. `P.TranReference LIKE N'Burden%'` would be a much better choice (assuming `TranReference` is already an `nvarchar`).

Comment: @ThomA - Googling the table names (LaborDtl PartTran) probably Epicor's table design rather than the OP's. What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Anyway whatever version it is the dupe should have you covered as it contains pretty much every alternative

Comment: I don't see the problem you're having at all. Replace the last pipe with another special character, and then use another parsename to parse that combined string into two new columns and voila. A someone less worse solution would be to convert the pipe string to json by replacing '|' with '","', wrapping the whole shebang into [] and using json_value(pipeDream, '$[0]') etc. You can also upgrade to sql server 2022 where string_split has positional argument

Comment: We are on SQL Server 2017 and upgrading to 2022 is not an option for us. I tried using the SplitString function in the associated article but I don't think I set up the call right because it never returned or crashed. The original query ran in 45 seconds with the same test data. All the solutions I have read seem like they would be more complicated when used within the join statement. I am not SQL savvy enough to understand how to set up these solutions. What is the best way to replace the parsename part of the join  -   on L.EmployeeNum = parsename(Replace(p.TranReference,'|','.'),3)

Comment: As your difficulty is with integrating the string split into the join rather than splitting the string in the first place I'll reopen

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty is integrating the string split into the join when going from a scalar function to a function returning a table. As you aren't on SQL Server 2022 `STRING_SPLIT` is not suitable for you anyway as it contains no information on `ordinal`.

In replacing the `PARSENAME` usage I'd likely use a `CROSS APPLY` returning a single row with all the required string elements and then use that in the Join.

Please see the following examples ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-fvyGXMq))

**Setup**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(Id INT, csv varchar(100));
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(Id INT, Name VARCHAR(10));

INSERT @Table1(Id, csv)
    VALUES (1, 'value1,2,3,Value4'),  
           (2, 'fo{o,4,5,qwerty');

INSERT @Table2(Id, Name)
    VALUES (1, 'Adam'),
           (2, 'Bob'),
           (3, 'Charles'),
           (4, 'David'),
           (5, 'Ed');
```

**PARSENAME example - Note 1..4 are descending string order**

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       PN1 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 1), 
       PN2 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 2), 
       PN3 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 3), 
       PN4 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 4),
       NameA = T2A.Name,
       NameB = T2B.Name
FROM @Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2A ON PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 3) = T2A.Id
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2B ON PARSENAME(REPLACE(t1.csv, ',', '.'), 2) = T2B.Id
```

**SQL Server 2022 example - Note 1..4 are ascending string order**

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
        NameA = T2A.Name,
        NameB = T2B.Name
FROM @Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(csv, ',', 1)
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [ordinal] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS P
) CA
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2A ON CA.[2] = T2A.Id
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2B ON CA.[3] = T2B.Id
```

**SQL Server+ 2016 OPENJSON - Note now 0 based and 0..3 are ascending string order**

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       [0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
        NameA = T2A.Name,
        NameB = T2B.Name
FROM @Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT [0],[1],[2],[3]
FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(csv, 'JSON'), ',', '","') + '"]')
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [key] IN ([0],[1],[2],[3])) AS P
) CA
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2A ON CA.[1] = T2A.Id
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2B ON CA.[2] = T2B.Id
```